# Shell Extension in the Command Prompt

Tags: windows, command-prompt, windows-shell

I have a shell extension installed into the filesystem by adding ".{CLSID}" to the folder name. The Shell Extension is like the .zip extension (allowing you to see files). Explorer handles it fine, but how do I get other program to recognize the sub files/folder (programs like command shell). I navigate to the directory with the shell and it shows the empty folder (also, it doesnt strip away the clsid). Is there some way to implement that functionality? Do I have to install the extension in a different way?

Thanks!

chacham15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, there is no documented way to add an extension to the windows cli shell (cmd.exe).

There is an add on shell for windows called [4NT](http://www.jpsoft.com/tcmddes.htm) that is extensible.

That said, you'll still end up writing scripts if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: +1. Those folders are not real directories. Only the shell (and programs which use its namespace APIs) knows about virtual folders; everything else only understands real directories.

Comment: Yea, i know. But one alternative is to create a custom filesystem bu that is a lot of work and I was hoping that there was an easier way.